# Importing external JAR file in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, automated-tests

I cannot get the import option in Selenium after adding the jar File to Eclipse. I tried with an older version as well and could not resolve it.

Steps that I have tried:

1. Opened the Eclipse application
2. Clicked on new Java project
3. Created the project with some name
4. Clicked on project Navigated New Class
5. Entered the class name with void main check box created the class
6. Clicked on the Project Navigated to the Build path and selected the Library option
7. With the external jar file option, attached the jar file to try to access the import option in editor

Actual result: Unable to see the import option when I hover on the code

Comment: What .jar file?  What import?